# How to best present edit icons for table rows that utilize multiple rowspans

Tags: tables, data-tables

I have a table that presents data like this:

[image: Table]

Each item has one row of basic information, e.g. name, size, category, etc., but also multiple rows of purchasing information, e.g. supplier, cost, etc. because each item can be purchased from multiple suppliers.

I need to present an edit icon to edit the basic information:

[image]


And also an edit icon to edit each individual purchasing information:

[image]


Alternatively I can present it like this, but i'm not sure if this is better:

[image]

I don't feel my solutions are that clear to the users. Any suggestions on how to best handle this situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The way you have it right now there are 3 edit buttons and it is not really clear what modifies which until the user clicks, opens and then sees it.

I suggest you **use only one edit button which switches between view mode and edit mode**. Then in the edit mode you can display the different editable areas to the user as you think it best fits. Having a button to edit each individual section (from the view mode) might be easier for the power user but not for the less experienced user.